# What is the 'Mathematica-way' to test a variable transform?

Tags: coordinate-transformation

Hello Mathematica experts.

I would like to play around with a simple variable transformation, to test some claims about it. I wonder if there is a *Mathematica*-like way to do this.

The specific case I have is a transformation:
$$x\mapsto x' \equiv \begin{cases}x; \qquad x\ge 0\\x+\pi;\, x<0\end{cases}$$
where $x\in[-\pi,\pi]$ gets moved over to $x'\in[0,\pi]$.

So far I have found two equivalent ways of representing this:

```
XPrimed[x_] := If[x < 0, x + π, x]
AnotherXPrimed[x_] := x*HeavisideTheta[x]  + (HeavisideTheta[-x]*(x + π))
```

Which both seem reasonable.

```
Plot[XPrimed[phi], {phi, -π, π}, 
    AxesLabel -> {"original variable, x", "transformed variable, x'"}, 
    PlotRange -> {{-π, π}, {0, π}}]
```

[image: Plot of the transformation... works as expected]

So how do I make plots of things like:

```
Plot[Cos[XPrimed[x]], {x,-π, π},
    AxesLabel -> {"original variable, x", "Cos(x')"}]
```

[image: Plot of the transformed variable]

..but over the **transformed** domain, i.e. $\cos(x')$ with $x'$ on the x-axis?
I suspect there is a smart way to do this in *Mathematica* specifying domains or variable maps or a coordinate transformation or the like, I can't seem to find anything.

Comment: Take a minute to think what you are asking - does it make any difference whether the variable is primed or not in your question?

Comment: Here is another valid way to define `XPrimed`: `XPrimed[x_] := Piecewise[{{x, x >= 0}, {x + π, x < 0}}]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ParametricPlot[{XPrimed[x], Cos[XPrimed[x]]}, {x, -\[Pi], \[Pi]}, 
  PlotStyle -> Thick, 
  AxesLabel -> (Style[#, 16] & /@ {"transformed variable, x'",  "Cos(x')"})]
```

[image]

Comment: That's really useful. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

As per m_goldberg, you can define transform as function and compose e.g.

```
g[x_] := Piecewise[{{x, x >= 0}, {x + Pi, True}}]
Plot[g[x], {x, -3, 3}, PlotLegends -> "Expressions"],
Plot[Cos[g[x]], {x, -3, 3}, PlotLegends -> "Expressions"]}]
```

[image]